# Getting No manifest attribute, in t.jar file

Tags: maven, jar

I am using Intellij Idea and i had created a simple maven project but when i create a jar file and make it run on the terminal it shows me error :
"no main manifest attribute, in target/JMS-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
My pom.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>JMS</groupId>
<artifactId>JMS</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- TEST SCOPE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So, i want to know that how to generate a jar file.

Comment: Do you really want to create a test-jar ? I assume no. So don't define maven-jar-plugin or correctly via pluginManagement and not goal execution except if you really know what you are doing. The junit dependency should be in `<scope>test</scope>`...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying 
But you can add manifest to jar see https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

i.e in plugin you need to specify tag true

sample code
`<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <classpathPrefix>../../../../../..</classpathPrefix>
                            <classpathLayoutType>repository</classpathLayoutType>
                            <mainClass>com.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Build>1</Implementation-Build>
                            <Implementation-Version>1.2</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
</plugin>`

Comment: Did not getting the answer It still says Admission class is not present

Comment: _Admission class?_